# Why I can't set a value on a asp:CheckBox?

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox

There isn't the attribute `Value` :

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
```

while on standard HTML this is allowed :

```
<input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox1" value="My Valyue" />
```

why?

Comment: @Mr Lister : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_checkbox.asp

Comment: Oops. My mind must have been somewhere else, sorry.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `Text` property is used to render a label for the checkbox.

The control has an [`InputAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.inputattributes.aspx) property that you can add to:

```
myChk.InputAttributes.Add("value", "My Value");
```

I believe that if you simply add the `value` attribute to the markup, this will also get populated.

You can access the value like so:

```
myChk.InputAttributes["value"];
```

---

To answer the question of *why* `Value` is not a build in attribute to the `CheckBox` control:

A `CheckBox` in isolation (just by itself) needs no value. By definition it is a boolean and is identified by its ID. All you need to do is check whether it was checked or not.

The value comes into play when you *group* checkboxes and there is a control for that - the [`CheckBoxList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx).) that uses [`ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) - each `ListItem` does have a `Value` property.

Comment: that seems odd, i get it for other controls but Checkboxes? Value seems to make more sense. I guess its all about inheritence from a GenericElement and the like for iteration across common interfaces.

Comment: NO! Text property is supposed to be the "label" near the checkbox, not the value of the checkbox itself..

Comment: @MrLister - If you have _several_ checkboxes with the same _name_ attribute (making them part of a group), how would you distinguish them? This attribute has been part of checkboxes for a long time.

Comment: @MrLister - Not at all. We sometimes forget that checkboxes can be grouped this way...

Comment: Yeah, but I'm supposed to know things like that; to be familiar with HTML. And of course the `value` of a checkbox gets posted when a form is submitted, anyone can see that!

Comment: Yeah, this is a great workaround! But my question is : why .NET doesnt have `value` attribute? :)

Comment: @markzzz - Well... something to ask the creators of the controls. Chances are that they has the same reasoning that MrLister gave, namely that a checkbox in isolation needs no value. By definition it is a boolean and is identified by its ID. The value comes into play when you _group_ checkboxes and guess what, there is a control for that - the [`CheckBoxList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the asp:CheckBox control, use the html input checkbox, and run it at the server.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ck" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("Value") %>' />
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ck" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Now you can reference it from codebehind as an HtmlInputCheckBox (my latest example is inside a repeater, so I can decorate this substitute for a checkbox list with other elements, like a tool tip image).

```
foreach (RepeaterItem repeaterItem in repCheckboxes.Items)
{
    HtmlInputCheckBox listItem = (HtmlInputCheckBox)repeaterItem.FindControl("ck");
    if (listItem.Checked)
    {
         string val = listItem.Value;
         ...
```

I know this does not answer the "why" of the OP, but this comes up high in searches for this exact problem, and this is a good solution.  As for why, I think MS goofed by leaving it out, since you don't have control over the html in a CheckBoxList